# What kind of technology is required for Alpha Centauri communication?

Tags: communication

Let's assume we already colonised Alpha Centauri.

What kind of technology we need in order to send and receive 1kbps?

Radio satellite orbiting the sun? How much power, antenna size and solar panel size? What frequency?

Related questions

[How powerful an antenna needs to be to signal Earth from other solar systems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16803/how-powerful-an-antenna-needs-to-be-to-signal-earth-from-other-solar-systems)

Comment: These are different questions, but related: [Breakthrough Starshot's 100 Gigawatt laser array - what's the current thinking how this might work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20036/12102) and [How are the tiny spacecraft proposed by Project Starshot supposed to communicate with Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20546/12102)

Comment: If we already got the technology to colonise Alpha Centauri, we have the technology needed for communication. Colonisation flights would be impossible without it.

Comment: Ok then assume AC has a civilisation advanced at the same level with us

Comment: It is ok to wait 4 years to download a lot of useful data like their best technology. The question still remains - what kind of technology we have to use to transmit and receive such data

Comment: @WOW6EQUJ5 entangled photons travel at the same speed as any other photons, in the context of this question I don't think there is any scenario whereby entangled photons can speed up the time it takes to get data from there back to here. If you can cite one that's been peer-reviewed, please do! Otherwise it might not be good to muddy the water by suggesting there are "unconvinced scientists".

Comment: We ask them: please send your most valuable data. We get the answer in 8.6 years. But it is really worth!

Comment: @uhoh You are right. So far no one proved in practice that superluminal communication is possible. I will delete comment. Just in case I don't turn out to muddy the water, I will list one source https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1275/1/012035/pdf where from the abstract itself it can be seen that there are physicists who assume that superluminal communication can still be achieved. From the reference list of that source one can find the works of these physicists.

Comment: @WOW6EQUJ5 That's a really cool paper! I don't understand it completely but it seems to be quite a novel approach. The abstract says only “To recover the locality principe some physicists suggested that the correlations between entangled particles could be established by communications propagating with a velocity $v_t$>c in a preferred frame.” and *could be established* means only *showing X can establish Y* in the same way that "the existence of three-eyed ghosts could be established if one were captured and analyzed." It doesn't say either way if the authors believe it's possible nor not.

Comment: @uhoh In text there is a part: “Superluminal communications between only two entangled particles could not be used to exchange informations in the macroscopic world (signaling), but it was recently shown [18][19] that superluminal communications between three or four entangled particles allow signaling.” Referenced papers are: https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3795
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236124868_In_search_of_superluminal_quantum_communications_Recent_experiments_and_possible_improvements/link/5416c1b00cf2788c4b35e48e/download

Comment: @WOW6EQUJ5 the *peer reviewed* work is in [Nature Physics](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2460) and that ends with "Note that as with usual Bell experiments, *depending on the assumption that one is willing to take, an experimental test of v-causal models may also need to overcome various loopholes. The way to remove these assumptions and overcome these loopholes is an interesting question that goes beyond the scope of our work* but some possibilities are discussed in Supplementary Information SE." This is just a hypothetical experiment only partially thought out with outstanding issues

Comment: @WOW6EQUJ5 **This says a lot less** than what you make it sound like it does.